# "Functions may be exported so that subshells automatically have them defined with the `-f` option to the `export` builtin"

Tags: bash

From [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html):

> Functions may be exported so that subshells automatically have them defined with the `-f` option to the `export` builtin.

What does it mean?

Does it mean:

> Functions may be exported by the `-f` option to the `export` builtin, so that subshells automatically have them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The -f flag is required for bash to interpret it as a function rather than a variable. See the [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html).